Change x-axis scale to cuberoot without transforming raw data using trans_new()
I need to change the x-axis of my ggplot figure to a cuberoot scale, without transforming the raw data. My code below had been working but with the new R update, I am getting the error,
Error in if (zero_range(as.numeric(transformation$transform(limits)))) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
I'm wondering if anyone knows why this error is occurring now and/or solutions/workarounds to plot my figure on the cuberoot scale. Thanks!
First few lines of data:
structure(list(site = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US"), 
    Transect = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Plot = c(100L, 103L, 
    106L, 109L, 112L, 115L), Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L), SYear = c("2020-2021", "2020-2021", "2020-2021", 
    "2020-2021", "2020-2021", "2020-2021"), E.Delta = c(-0.0380000000000109, 
    -0.0930000000000746, -0.0950000000000273, -0.0709999999999127, 
    -0.104000000000042, -0.0989999999999327), I = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), AllRtedPctCov = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), NoRtedVeg = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PerCov.15 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

**My code: **
transform_cuberoot = function(){
  trans_new('cuberoot',
            transform = function(x) x^(1/3),
            inverse = function(x) x^3,
            breaks = c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0),
            domain = c(-Inf, Inf))
} 

 
ggplot(df, aes(x = I, y = E.Delta, color = PerCov.15)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(~site + SYear, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
  labs(x = "Inundation-Duration", y = "Change in Elevation", color =" Percent Rooted Cover") +
  scale_colour_brewer(labels= c("<15%", ">15%"), type = "qual", palette = 3) + # qual 3 or seq 1
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16, vjust = -2),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, vjust = 5),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2), "cm"),
        panel.spacing = unit(3, "lines"))+
  scale_x_continuous(trans = transform_cuberoot(), breaks = c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0),labels=c(0, 0.01, 0.1, " ", 0.3, " ", " ", 0.6, " ", " ", " ", 1.0)) 


I have also tried using the workaround,
coord_trans(x = transform_cuberoot())

instead of of the trans = transform_cuberoot() argument in scale_x_continuous. This works but removes other important plotting features such as the dashed line at y = 0 and the y-axis line. It also produces 18 warnings of:

In transform(..., self = self) :
Transformation introduced infinite values in x-axis

See below for an example of the figure I'm looking for versus what I'm able to produce with the workaround.
What I want/trying to re-create (with a horizontal line at 0 and wrapped for each site):

What I currently have with the workaround:


With the data subset you provided I'm not getting any warnings or errors and do see a horizontal line at zero (R 4.4.1, ggplot2 3.5.1). Can you make sure this still happens from a clean session and post the results of sessionInfo() ?

@BenBolker I tried from a clean session and still got the error. I checked that there are no NAs in the dataset, and that the data falls within normal limits for each parameter (i.e., Inundation-duration on the x-axis is between 0 and 1). Here is the session info:

R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)
Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8
time zone: America/Denver
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_1.3.1          scales_1.3.0         EnvStats_2.8.1
[4] scatterplot3d_0.3-44 car_3.1-2            carData_3.0-5
[7] DHARMa_0.4.6         glmmTMB_1.1.9        nlme_3.1-165
[10] lme4_1.1-35.4        Matrix_1.7-0         dplyr_1.1.4
[13] ggplot2_3.5.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] gtable_0.3.5        compiler_4.4.0      tidyselect_1.2.1
[4] Rcpp_1.0.13         splines_4.4.0       boot_1.3-30
[7] lattice_0.22-6      R6_2.5.1            generics_0.1.3
[10] MASS_7.3-60.2       tibble_3.2.1        nloptr_2.1.0
[13] munsell_0.5.1       minqa_1.2.7         pillar_1.9.0
[16] TMB_1.9.14          rlang_1.1.4         utf8_1.2.4
[19] cli_3.6.2           withr_3.0.0         magrittr_2.0.3
[22] mgcv_1.9-1          grid_4.4.0          rstudioapi_0.16.0

[25] lifecycle_1.0.4     vctrs_0.6.5         glue_1.7.0
[28] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 abind_1.4-5         fansi_1.0.6
[31] colorspace_2.1-0    purrr_1.0.2         tools_4.4.0
[34] pkgconfig_2.0.3

You can fix the issue by restricting the domain for your cuberoot transformation to non-negative values, i.e. use domain=c(0, Inf).
Note: As already pointed out by @BenBolker the issue is not reproducible using your example data, so I altered it to include a zero value. After some experimenting the issue arises only when the variable mapped on x includes some small, nearly zero values. From this I would guess that this has to do with the (default) expansion of the scale and as a confirmation of my guess I tried with expand = c(0, 0) which also works fine even for a domain=c(-Inf, Inf).
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df$I <- c(0.0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0)
transform_cuberoot <- function() {
  trans_new("cuberoot",
    transform = function(x) x^(1 / 3),
    inverse = function(x) x^3,
    domain = c(0, Inf)
  )
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = I, y = E.Delta, color = PerCov.15)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ site + SYear, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
  labs(
    x = "Inundation-Duration", y = "Change in Elevation",
    color = " Percent Rooted Cover"
  ) +
  scale_colour_brewer(
    labels = c("<15%", ">15%"),
    type = "qual", palette = 3
  ) + # qual 3 or seq 1
  scale_x_continuous(
    transform = transform_cuberoot(),
    breaks = c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0)
  )


Just as a reference, here I reproduce the issue using domain = c(-Inf, Inf):
transform_cuberoot <- function() {
  trans_new("cuberoot",
    transform = function(x) x^(1 / 3),
    inverse = function(x) x^3,
    domain = c(-Inf, Inf)
  )
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = I, y = E.Delta, color = PerCov.15)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ site + SYear, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
  labs(
    x = "Inundation-Duration", y = "Change in Elevation",
    color = " Percent Rooted Cover"
  ) +
  scale_colour_brewer(
    labels = c("<15%", ">15%"),
    type = "qual", palette = 3
  ) + # qual 3 or seq 1
  scale_x_continuous(
    transform = transform_cuberoot(),
    breaks = c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0)
  )
#> Error in if (zero_range(as.numeric(transformation$transform(limits)))) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed


This worked! Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for several days. I really appreciate you taking the time to find an answer and help me.
